# Fill null values in array with previous value (not-null) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, null

I have a dynamic array which displays values as shown below:

```
$val_array = array("1","2","","","4","","","","","");
```

Below is the code that simply echos out the values:

```
foreach($val_array as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;    
}
```

The result of this is:

```
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => null
[3] => null
[4] => 4
[5] => null
[6] => null
[7] => null
[8] => null
[9] => null
```

What I would like to achieve is to replace the null values with the most previous non-null value as shown below:

```
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 2
[3] => 2
[4] => 4
[5] => 4
[6] => 4
[7] => 4
[8] => 4
[9] => 4
```

I've tried including an if statement to check if the null value exists and then including the prev function but it stops at the 2nd value:

```
foreach($val_array as $key => $value) {

    if (empty($val_array)) {
        $value = prev($val_array);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if(empty($val_array))` is never going to be true since $val_array is not empty.  You need to check if each value is greater than 0, or you could also check `strlen($value)>0` if you're working with non-numeric values.

This should work:

```
$last_value=NULL;

foreach($val_array as $value) {

    if ($value>0) {
        $last_value = $value;
    }else{
        $value = $last_value;
    }
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @daniel for the swift response! I tried it out and it worked perfectly. I tried overcomplicating it with using prev, next functions and it came down to a good old if statement. Thank you very much for your answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, depending on how your array is getting generated (coming from DB or something) - you could do different things.

Just going off of your question, I will assume that it is not so this might give you and idea to get going again.

You have your "new" array:

```
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 3
[3] => null
...
```

In your each method, I would write a check for the null (kind of like you have) like this:

```
for ($i=0; i<newArray.length; i++)
{
    if ( newArray[i] == null )
    {
         newArray[i] = getOldArrayValue(i);
    }
}

getOldArrayValue(index) {
   // Origional array is generated...
   $oldArray = array();
   oldArray[0] => 1
   oldArray[1] => 2
   oldArray[2] => 3
   oldArray[3] => 4

  return oldArray[i];
}
```

If your array is coming from a DB, then you could always make a query for the array value.

Comment: Thank you @dragonslovetacos for your answer! I didn't see your answer until I finished testing daniels but I really do appreciate your help :) You're correct the array was coming from the DB that's why there were irregular null values. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple for loop you can use:

```
$val_array = array("1","2","","","4","","","","","");
$count = count($val_array);
$last = 0; // if the first values are null or false it will be set to 0
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    if($val_array[$i] == false){
        $val_array[$i] = $last;
    } else {
        $last = $val_array[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't think of using a for loop! Thanks for your answer @akshay2598

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a for is better than a foreach ;)

```php
if($val_array[0] === NULL){
  $val_array[0] = "defaultValue";
}

for($i=1; $i < count($val_array); $i++){
  if($val_array[$i] === NULL){
    $val_array[$i] = $val_array[$i-1];
  }
}
```